# Android, quick question from my book

Tags: android, multithreading, messaging

I am a noob learning Android via a book, i have a quick question. My book code is pretty simple and looks like this:

My handler:

```
 Handler handler=new Handler() { 
    @Override 
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
      bar.incrementProgressBy(5); 
              } 
  };
```

My thread:

```
Thread background=new Thread(new Runnable() { 
          public void run() { 
            try { 
              for (int i=0;i<20 && isRunning.get();i++) { 
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
                handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage()); 
              } 
            } 
            catch (Throwable t) { 
              // just end the background thread 
            } 
          } 
        });
```

My question is here:

```
handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
```

What the heck is "handler.obtainMessage()" ?
Doing a mouse over in Eclipse gives me a message that sounds like gibberish.
What message is it trying to "obtain"?

Comment: sendMessage should send a simple string. so i think obtainMessage() should retrieve your own constant string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#obtainMessage%28%29), it obtains a message from the message pool instead of creating a new one. (you need to send a message to the handler anyway):

> Returns a new Message from the global message pool. More efficient
>   than creating and allocating new instances. The retrieved message has
>   its handler set to this instance (Message.target == this). If you
>   don't want that facility, just call Message.obtain() instead.

I'll try to elaborate:

You send a message to the handler. The message is added to the handler's thread queue and processed on the original thread. You need to send it a message, though you have nothing specific in the message that it uses (according to your handler code) so you just send an empty message, but instead of allocating a memory for a new message, the message is taken from the message pool, which is faster.

Hope this makes things clearer.

Regarding how to set a message with an int:

```
Message m = new Message();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("what", 5); // for example
m.setData(b);
handler.sendMessage(m);
```

Comment: Yep, thats the explanation I came across as well via google and Eclipse (that i wrote in the OP), and I dont understand it too well.  Can you explain it a little more please?

Comment: Thank you! That makes a bit more sense, I have chosen your answer but would appreciate it if you could just answer me one related q...right now i have nothing specific in the message (as you said), how can i have something specific? I tried sending an int in sendmessage but that did not work...

Comment: i edited my code to see what the message was: tView1.setText("r:"+msg); and it shows me "what" and "when", so i tried to change the value of "what" by passing an int, but it did not work :(

Comment: You need to create a message object and put an `int` in its bundle. I will add a few lines to the answer, but I have to go...

Comment: Aha! Thats opened it up for me, thank you SO much for your help and have a wonderful day!